# Sftp in MobaXterm

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, remote-access, mobaxterm

How can i get in MobaXterm's sftp directory, current server's directory when entering in nested servers. For example:  First login in server 192.xxxx...@user.com and from there connect to server 192.xxxx...@user.com. I want in sftp files bar(on the left) to see second server's  user directories but i got the first ones. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe here is called a jump-host-scenario.

Open a local terminal in mobaxterm and enter:

```sh
ssh -J user@hosta.foo user@hostb.foo
```

After successful login you see hostb.foo's directory listing in the left sftp browser window.

For background, perhaps see also
https://www.tecmint.com/access-linux-server-using-a-jump-host/

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer your question directly, but you can get around this problem by scp'ing the files from the second server to the first server. You can then sftp the files from the first server to your desktop or wherever.